# For what values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ the above system has: One solution. Infinitely many solutions. No solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am stuck with this now, I tried reducing the matrix to row echelon form, but it gets a bit hard. Is there not a simpler way?

The system is:

\begin{align*}
a x + b y − 3 z &= −3\\
−2 x − b y + c z &= −1\\
a x + 3 y − c z &= −3
\end{align*}

Comment: Reducing the matrix to a row echelon is probably the best thing to do even if some computations are required.

Comment: Yes, the calculations in this case are really disgusting...but there's hardly any other simpler way to do it. Reduce to echelon form.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the determinant of the system, you will get
$$
2abc-3ab-3ac-2bc+18
$$
When is this zero? Well, we can solve for $c$,
$$
c = \frac{3(ab-6)}{2ab-3a-2b}
$$
as long as $2ab-3a-2b \neq 0$.
So when is $2ab-3a-2b = 0$? More algebra gives us
$$
b = \frac{3a}{2(a-1)}
$$
if $a \neq 1$. What about when $a=1$? Then $2ab-3a-2b = -3 \neq 0$, so we would be in the first case. Otherwise, let's substitute that value of $b$ in to the original equation, we get
$$
0  =3(ab-6) = 3(a\frac{3a}{2(a-1)} - 6) = \frac{a-2}{a-1}
$$
which implies $a=2$ which implies $b=3$.

To summarize, the equation will have a unique solution *unless*
$$
2ab-3a-2b \neq 0 \text{ and } c = \frac{3(ab-6)}{2ab-3a-2b}
$$
or
$$
a=2, b=3, c = \text{anything}
$$

Now for these possibilities, what happens? If $a=2,b=3$ then row 2 is the negative of row 3, but $-1$ is not the negative of $-3$, so there are *no* solutions. Then try using row echelon form on the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: eliminating $y,z$ we get the following equation for $x$:
$$2 b c x-7 b c+9 b+9 c-18 x+9=a x (2 b c-3 b-3 c)$$

Comment: I am sorry, I do not see how can I carry on from here to solve the question!

Comment: solve this equation for $x$ and the denominator must be not equal zero

Comment: If b=3,c not 3 then no solution. If b=3,c=3 then infinitely many solutions. If b is not 3 then the solution exists and it is unique. The details are inconvenient to write!